# LockScreen widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ios16, home-screen-widget, flutter-lockscreenwidget, android-lockscreenwidget

There are some plugins like [home_widget: ^0.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget/example) that supports only `HomeScreen Widgets`.

Recently Apple launched `LockScreen Widgets` on iOS 16.

Is there any plugin for that? How do I implement that?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26134

Answer (score 4):

At the time of this writing, there are no known plugins that do that. There are two options moving forward, based on timeline for when you need this functionality:

1. Wait for someone to create a plugin that does this
2. Create the plugin yourself. Follow the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-lock-screen-widgets-and-watch-complications) and write a custom Flutter plugin (and then preferably publish it to [pub.dev](https://www.pub.dev) for others to benefit from as well).

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is native functionality, as @Shredder2794 said, if anyone has not created a plugin for that purpose, we have to build it.

You have to write separate native codes for iOS and Android with [platform channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)